# getting value and id from a React MaterialUI RadioButtonGroup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to get the selected `value` and `gameID` from a dynamic MaterialUI RadioButtonGroup.

> Doing it like this i can get the `gameID`, but not the `value`:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleEmailNotifications}>
    <ul>
        {profile.games.map((game) => {
            return (
                <li key={game.game_id}>
                    <RadioButtonGroup
                        name={game.game_title}
                        onChange={() => this.handleGameNewsChange(event, value, game)}>
                        <RadioButton
                            value="yes"
                            label="Yes"
                        />
                        <RadioButton
                            value="no"
                            label="No"
                        />
                    </RadioButtonGroup>
                </li>
            )
        })}
    </ul>
</form>


handleGameNewsChange(event, value, game) {
    console.log(event, value, game)
} 
//output undefinded, undefined, game
```

Changing from

```
onChange={() => this.handleGameNewsChange(event, value, game)}
```

to

```
onChange={this.handleGameNewsChange}>
```

> I can get the `value` but not the `gameID`

**How can i get both?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not passing the `event` and `value` in [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), write it like this:

```
onChange={(event, value) => this.handleGameNewsChange(event, value, game)}>
```

That's why `event` and `value` was undefined.